# SOLVED Redshift on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, display, opengles

Is there any way to use Redshift on Raspberry Pi 4? I used redshift -P -O 3700 -g 0.7 -b 0.7 and it only works from time to time. Some times after restarting it doesnt filter the blue light anymore. Tried to enable openGL but still doesn't work. Or is there any other app that would dim the light?

Answer (score 0):

found the clue

```
ddcutil setvcp 10 50
ddcutil setvcp 12 50
```

will do it

Comment: Care to elaborate? This does not work on my pi,it fails with "Display not found".